# Feasible Type Theories

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, computational-complexity, type-theory, constructive-mathematics

I am looking for references about efficient type theories,
efficiency in the sense of [computational complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory),
and type theory in the sense of [Martin-Lof's type theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_type_theory). 
Has there been any studies with the goal of creating efficient versions of these theories?

Note: I am familiar with Stephen Cook and Alasdair Urquhart's theory $\mathsf{PV^\omega}$ and their "[Functional Interpretations of Feasibly Constructive Arithmetic](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~sacook/homepage/cook_urquhart.ps)" paper from 1989 ([doi:10.1145/73007.73017](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/73007.73017)), but that is type theory in the sense of [Kurt Godel's System $\mathsf{T}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialectica_interpretation). I am looking for feasible type theories in the sense of Martin-Lof's type theory.

Comment: I think feasibility and dependent product types don't fit together particularly well. Even for simple arrow types, there is a problem in getting an evaluation map $(f,x)\mapsto f(x):[X\to Y]\times X\to Y$ which is feasible (e.g. assuming polytime complexity). An elegant solution to that problem would be very interesting.